# Angular detect leaving a route.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.5 and ui-router.  I want to detect when a user `leaves` a route.  I've currently got something like:

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function () {
      if (!$scope.flag) {
        //...
        $scope.do_work(reason);
      }
    });
```

this doesn't quite work because when the user navigates to the this route, `$scope.flag` is set to `false` and this function incorrectly fires.  Is there an idiomatic way to fire a function when a user navigates away from a particular route, but not when they navigate to it?

Comment: when it navigates **to** it, it is coming from another route(which navigates away). So it always gets fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say use [**`onExit`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks) hook of `ui-router` which you can specify on single state. But you can't access `$scope` inside it.

To deal with it, I'd say maintain service which will have shareable data. Change that shareable data from `onExit` hook of your desired state. Then you can access the same service inside your controller as well.

```
$stateProvider.state("contacts", {
  template: '<h1>Dummy Template</h1>',
  controller: 'myCotroller',
  onExit: function(sharableService){
    //... do something sharableService variable...
  }
})
```

Comment: this sounds like the best available solution, but I'm not sure I i want to create a service that only has the state of one variable in it.  I was able to get around it by using `rootScope` instead of scope, which isn't a good solution.

Comment: Don't go for rootScope, create service only.rather say it as some general name like `sharedDataService` and have you variable there, may be in future you could have more variable data and methods there..

Comment: I ended up using `$scope.$destroy`.  I tried injecting a service with $stateProvider in the config function of angular, but that wouldn't work.

Comment: angular throws an exception when you try to inject a service into the config part of the life cycle.